# Credit card debt after cosigner passed away

Tags: united-states, debt, inheritance, co-sign

My father is a cosigner  on my brothers credit cards. He passed away last month. My brother is not paying off the debt. Can we remove my fathers name? Is my dads  estate responsible?  My brother owes more than the estate  is worth. My mom will be left destitute  if the credit companies  go after the estate.

Comment: How much are we talking about here?  What state?

Comment: We need to know which jurisdiction you are in. The other complication is what type of state it is for community property.

Comment: Have they already come after your father for the debt?

Comment: If it goes to court, try to force trial by jury.

Comment: I wouldn't contact the credit card company at all.

Comment: Find a lawyer yesterday

Comment: @HankyPanky or find a baseball bat to get the brother in line.

Comment: Condolences here for your father to you and your family.

Comment: My mom is in I)linois. The estate is only about 150,000. The debt on the car loans my brother has in my dads name is about 70,000. Credit cards are over  60,000.  I am not executer. My older brother is in charge and he won't  get a lawyer because  he thinks he can do it himself. He got one of those living trusts on the Internet  and thinks he can protect her estate by putting it in trust.

Comment: @Nursefun1952 He needs an immediate dose of reality--living trusts are about avoiding probate, not about shielding her assets.

Comment: If so far he or your dad has been paying the minimum you probably want to make sure the minimum payments continue being made. Consult a lawyer but you probably don't want them looking for unpaid cash while your dads estate still exists.

Answer (score 48):

Well, we need to know a lot more info, since where your mom lives will have an impact on what assets are at risk, but the general answer is yes, the assets of the estate are at risk, since your dad was 100% responsible for the debt. (This is what being a co-signer means.)

Removing his name from it would require the agreement of the card issuers and given that the debt isn't being serviced, I would be thunderstruck if they would agree to that.

You need legal representation immediately.

Comment: If this is a community property state, your mother could be liable for the debt, but it also depends on whether the debt or the marriage came first. http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/credit-card-debt-death.html and http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/debt-marriage-owe-spouse-debts-29572.html But you really should consult a lawyer.

Comment: It does matter often if the spouse was a spouse at the time the card was opened, and if she also was a cosigner/authorized user on her husbands card. I have seen cases where a spouse was not immediately and personally liable on a debt she did not incur, however the estate is most likely still liable.

Comment: There is no way that the card companies  will keep my brother alone because he doesn't  pay his bills or only pays the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

If your mother is now the owner of all assets and obligations of your father, she may be able to cancel the card.

This does not deal with the damage that has already been done, but could limit the risk of building up more debt.

Comment: This is another thing to get advice on, and the advice needs to be specific to the jurisdiction. It's conceivable that the father('s estate) is in any case only co-signer for debts incurred up to his death, and/or that the obligation of being co-signer can't be inherited by the mother. Agreed it's right to communicate that *she* is not willing to co-sign.

Comment: A useful comment but this doesn't really attempt to answer the question.

Comment: I think it does partly answer the question about "removing the father's name"

Comment: Oh, and it's probably the executor, if there is one, who should be looking to stop co-signing new debt (presumably resulting in the lender cancelling the card, unless they decide they don't need a co-signer any more). But the executor's legal advisor and/or the lender can tell them how things stand.

Comment: Is my brother  allowed to keep using the credit cards even though  the cosigner  is deceased?

Comment: @Nursefun1952 60000$ is not limit !!??????

Comment: @Nursefun1952 In general, he can continue to use it until it is cancelled. His name is on it too. This is why cosigning cards is really dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Many credit cards have insurance premiums or options for the case of the individual being unable to pay the debt due to disability or death. Depending on the card and the options selected, it is possible that with the death of the cosigner that the insurance (if any) could cover the outstanding debt.

It is not likely and as Pieter B commented on OP's original post, contacting the credit card company is a risky move.

Comment: No insurance on the cards.